# Combine and sort 2 tables

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dataset

I have 2 DataTables (in a DataSet)

Table 1:

```
ID|ident  |Pos
------------------
0 | id425 | 0
1 | id123 | 3
```

Table 2:

```
ID|ident  |default|Pos
---------------------------
0 | id1   | 6     |2
1 | id180 | 6     |1
```

Now i want to do a sort with LINQ that produces the following output:

```
Result
ident|Pos
-------------
id425|0
id180|1
id1  |2
id123|3
```

Now im struggeling around with LINQ to achieve this with one linq query. I am new to LINQ so i hope somone has a hint for me. My problem is how to sort the two tables and combine the result.
My code so far is :

```
var query =
from t1 in dataSet.Tables[tableOne].AsEnumerable()
from t2 in dataSet.Tables[tableTwo].AsEnumerable()
orderby t1[Pos]
orderby t2[Pos]
select new {t1,t2};
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: `doesn't work` is a completely useless description of the issue. Please elaborate. Won't compile? Runtime exceptions? Unexpected output? What did you expect the output to be? What did it turn out to be instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i would use an anonymous type with the same columns to be able to use `Enumerable.Concat`. Then it's a simple `OrderBy`:

```
var t1Rows = dataSet.Tables[tableOne].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new{ ident=r.Field<string>("ident"),Pos=r.Field<int>("Pos") });
var t2Rows = dataSet.Tables[tableTwo].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new{ ident=r.Field<string>("ident"),Pos=r.Field<int>("Pos") }); 
var both = t1Rows.Concat(t2Rows);
var ordered = both.OrderBy(x => x.Pos);
```

The same in one query (for what it's worth, pure query-syntax not possible because of `Concat`):

```
var query = dataSet.Tables[tableOne].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { ident = r.Field<string>("ident"), Pos = r.Field<int>("Pos") })
    .Concat(dataSet.Tables[tableTwo].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { ident = r.Field<string>("ident"), Pos = r.Field<int>("Pos") }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Pos);
```

Comment: Now it works! thank you guys, you made may day! 
I actually used a combination of Tim and Bibhu's solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var result_datatable1 = from o in table1
              select new
              {
                  o.ident,
                  o.Pos
              };
var result_datatable2 = from o in tabl2
              select new
              {
                  o.ident,
                  o.Pos
              };

var resultSum = result_datatable1.Concat(result_datatable2);
```